# Replacing SQL database table with transformed data in dplyr

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, dplyr

I frequently replace data as I transform it in dplyr, especially when working with large datasets. I'm not sure how to do this elegantly when I am working with SQL-backed datasets, at least not with SQLite.

I could not find any discussion of this goal in the dplyr DB vignettes or on SO, which also makes me wonder if there's something wrong with what I'm doing in the first place; however, it seems to be a natural way to work with large datasets.

At any rate, the most intuitive approach does not work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)

db2 <- src_sqlite("trouble.sqlite", create = TRUE)
trouble <- data.frame(values = c(5, 1, 3))
trouble.db <- copy_to(db2, trouble, temporary = FALSE)

collect(trouble.db) # 5, 3, 1

trouble.db <- trouble.db %>% arrange(values)
collect(trouble.db) # 1, 3, 5

trouble.in <- tbl(db2, sql("SELECT * from trouble"))
collect(trouble.in) # 5, 3, 1
```

Another intuitive syntax for in-place copy gives a "table already exists" error:

```
trouble.db <- copy_to(db2, as.data.frame(trouble.db), name="trouble", temporary = FALSE)
```

One solution is to manually drop the table and rebuild it, which is what I've been doing:

```
db2$con %>% db_drop_table(table = "trouble")
trouble <- collect(trouble.db)
trouble.db <- copy_to(db2, trouble, temporary = FALSE)
```

Another one is to give up on replacement and create a series of temporary tables, which I find unaesthetic but which I suppose might be the recommended paradigm:

```
trouble_temp <- data.frame(values = c(5, 1, 3))
trouble_temp.db <- copy_to(db2, trouble_temp, temporary = TRUE)
trouble <- trouble.db %>% arrange(values)
trouble.db <- copy_to(db2, trouble, temporary = FALSE)
```

I suspect that "drop and re-copy" is going to wind up being the answer, but out of an abundance of love for beautiful solutions, I thought I would ask if there is a better way.

Comment: Hello David. Would you please provide some context around why you want to replace the original data in the database?  Given what you've already written, the safest procedure is to manipulate the data > write to new, permanent table on DBMS > DROP TABLE to delete the original table > ALTER TABLE to rename the new table with the original name.   This way you don't drop the original table until after the new data has been successfully saved in the DBMS.

Comment: Hi Greg, honestly, after almost two years, I don't remember what I was after. These days, I just use Spark for these kinds of things.

Comment: @ David Bruce: LOL, I was trying to find something to answer and then I saw your comment. Well, perhaps in two years I am also using spark, but now I just read tables from a SQL server with R.

Comment: I've been here too. @LenGreski, the one thing I'd add is that you can also use `copy_to` with a temp table, coupled with an `UPDATE` (or upsert) statement to the original table. I use this a lot because I'm working with tables with several dependencies where it's easier to preserve the original table (plus you get nice timestamp logging if you've got that set up). Happy to post an answer if that'd be helpful to have.

Comment: Views are your friends. You may even use temporary views (depending on what SQL flavour you have).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this years after.

The statement

```r
trouble.db %>% arrange(values)
```

Creates an SQL query that's sent to the database and executed when you `collect` the result.

We can see that SQL like this

```r
trouble.db %>% arrange(values) %>% show_query()
```

```
SELECT *
FROM `trouble`
ORDER BY `values`
```

Clearly a query like this can't modify the actual data it's querying.

To modify the data, we can use `dbWriteTable` function from the `DBI` package

```r
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)

# Will use this connection object for all our DB interactions
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = ":memory:")

trouble <- data.frame(values = c(5, 1, 3))
trouble.db <- copy_to(con, trouble, temporary = FALSE)

collect(trouble.db) # 5, 3, 1

# This is just a query
trouble.db <- trouble.db %>% arrange(values)
collect(trouble.db) # 1, 3, 5

# The data shouldn't be modified yet
trouble.in <- tbl(con, sql("SELECT * from trouble"))
collect(trouble.in) # 5, 3, 1

# Now we are modifying the data
DBI::dbWriteTable(
  con, "trouble", collect(trouble.db),
  overwrite = TRUE
)

tbl(con, sql("SELECT * from trouble")) %>% collect() # 1, 3, 5
```