# Modify existing and copy to new table in SQLServer using dplyr without using collect

Tags: sql-server, r, dplyr

I found [a question of similar nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343490/replacing-sql-database-table-with-transformed-data-in-dplyr), since the author switched to use another tools for data processing, I would like to continue his question.

In gist, I want to modify an existing table in SQLServer, then insert the new table into SQLServer, giving two tables in the database. Currently I am doing something like this:

```
copy_to(channel,iris,'##iris',temporary=FALSE)

iris.st01 <- tbl(channel,'##iris') %>%
  mutate(`Sepal.Length.Sq`=`Sepal.Length`^2) %>%
  collect

copy_to(channel,iris.st01,'##iris_st01',temporary=FALSE)
```

It is somewhat "less beautiful" to copy the dataframe out of the server, and then insert it again, given the all the changes can be done in the server. I wonder if there are any better ways for doing it?

Answer for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454816/create-consecutive-integer-and-then-create-index-to-a-table-stored-in-sqlserver) suggested using the `DBI` package, I wonder if this package can do similar trick.

Thanks!

#### Update 01

I followed suggestion from @Moody_Mudskipper and change my script as following:

```
copy_to(channel,iris,'##iris',temporary=FALSE)

iris.st01 <- tbl(channel,'##iris') %>%
  mutate(`Sepal.Length.Sq`=`Sepal.Length`^2) %>%
  collect

# copy_to(channel,iris.st01,'##iris_st01',temporary=FALSE)
db_drop_table(channel,'##iris_st01')
DBI::dbSendQuery(channel,'SELECT "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", POWER("Sepal.Length", 2.0) AS "Sepal.Length.Sq" INTO ##iris_st01 FROM ##iris')
```

It is working, while you can see the `SELECT "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", POWER("Sepal.Length", 2.0) AS "Sepal.Length.Sq"
FROM "##iris"` actually originates from:

```
> iris.st01 <- tbl(channel,'##iris') %>%
+     mutate(`Sepal.Length.Sq`=`Sepal.Length`^2) %>% show_query
<SQL>
SELECT "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", POWER("Sepal.Length", 2.0) AS "Sepal.Length.Sq"
FROM "##iris"
```

What I am thinking is to use `show_query` to show the SQL query and "inject" it into database via `DBI::dbSendQuery`, it seems not working to me when the query getting very long (e.g. with multiple joins).

Any clues here? Thanks!

Comment: You can use any SQL with `DBI::dbSendQuery` , here it would be something like `DBI::dbSendQuery(channel, "CREATE TABLE iris.st01 AS SELECT *, SQUARE(Sepal.Length) AS Sepal.Length.Sq FROM iris")` (not sure if it's valid in SQL server)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thanks, it solved the first part of my problem, actually I am working on a much longer query that seems `show_query` cannot show the entire query.

Comment: strange, can you try `dbplyr::sql_render` instead of `show_query` ?

Comment: You should use the `compute()` function